# Extra space in listview within AlertDialog using MultiChoiceItems

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-xml, android-alertdialog

For some reason, no matter what I change, I cannot get rid of the extra space after the last item in my `ListView`. You can see it here under "item 3".

[image: ShortList]

This happens even if I have a long list, and even if I pull down all the way.

[image: LongList]

I've tried every combination of `match_parent` and `wrap_content` in my layout with no success. Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my `AlertDialog`:

```
private void openMultiItemAlertDialog() {
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<CharSequence> itemsList = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    itemsList.add("item 1");
    itemsList.add("item 2");
    itemsList.add("item 3");
    itemsList.add("item 4");
    itemsList.add("item 5");
    itemsList.add("item 6");
    itemsList.add("item 7");
    itemsList.add("item 8");
    itemsList.add("item 9");

    final CharSequence[] finalItemsList = itemsList.toArray(
            new CharSequence[itemsList.size()]);

    boolean[] booleanPrimativeArray = new boolean[finalItemsList.length];
    checkedItems = new boolean[finalItemsList.length];
    selectedItems.clear();


    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
        .setView(view)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialogMultiItem = null;
            }
        })
        .setMultiChoiceItems(finalItemsList, booleanPrimativeArray, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                checkedItems[which] = isChecked;
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
                    if (checkedItems[i]) {
                        selectedItems.add((String) finalItemsList[i]);
                    }
                }
                doStuffWithSelectedItems(selectedItems);
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialogMultiItem = null;
            }
        });

    dialogMultiItem = dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: you are setting hieght as "wrap_content" try setting it as "fill_parent"
btw where are u declaring your buttons in xml ??

Comment: What is that .setView(view) doing there?

Comment: @r4jiv007 I've tried every possible combination of "wrap_content" and "match_parent". That's a good point to add to the question though. I've updated the question with that. And not to be pedantic but it's "match_parent" as of API level 8 :) As for the buttons, I'm not declaring them in XML. They're set in the AlertDialog builder.

Comment: @rhoadster91 good catch. I forgot to add that from my code. It's there now.

Comment: I don't think you need to use .setView(view) to add the multichoice list. Can you try without the setView and see if that works for you?

Comment: Nice find! It worked, thank you! So why is that? I'd speculate to say that the setMultiChoiceItems creates its own ListView within the dialog since it knows what kind of view you want and populates that with the supplied CharSequence[]. Then when I added my view to it and didn't fill my view with anything, it just added a blank space. If only there were something about setMultiChoiceItems doing this in the Android developer documentation... sigh...

Comment: Can you add the solution you gave and any information you know regarding why this happens to an answer?

Comment: @rhoadster91 Can you add the solution you gave and any information you know regarding why this happens to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlertDialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems method creates a list from the given array and supplies a listener to notify your app regarding changes. This method does *not* require setView to be called earlier, so by doing so, you are inflating an empty layout and adding it to the AlertDialog for no reason.

Although the documentation is a bit hazy on this point, I believe it, as you said in the comments, populates its own ListView with the CharSequence[] regardless of what view has been supplied to it via .setView() method.

Comment: So what is the solution to remove the extra space?

Comment: @Byron see rhoadster91's comment on my question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because your code instructs the builder to create two sets of data sources through calling

- setView()
- setMultiChoiceItems().
  together.

The same error will be caused if the code calls

- setView()
- setAdapter()

together.

The solution is to just call setAdapter(), Do Not call setView() extra.